# UK taxes for non UK citizen and non UK resident holding bank account in the UK

Tags: banking

I'm a non UK citizen (I'm Algerian) and non UK resident (I work in Saudi Arabia). I Hold a bank account with HSBC in UK. Do I have to pay taxes?